# Spring-JS unable to locate web-resources

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-js

I am using Spring JS 2.3.0 with Spring 3.0.5 and believe I have configured the applicationContext.xml properly for resources (css and js files). Here are the snippets:

applicationContext.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" />  

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

The jsp page

```
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/js/xwt/themes/reboot2/reboot2.css"/>">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/js/xwt/themes/reboot2/reboot2-xwt.css"/>">    

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/dojo/dojo.js"/>"></SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/Spring.js" />"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/Spring-Dojo.js" />"> </script>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When the jsp page is requested, the Spring.js and Spring-Dojo.js are not accessed while other resources under the app root are accessed. Btw, spring-js is under WEB-INF/lib folder. Firebug shows 404 for spring resources:

404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/springmvc/resources/Spring.js
404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/springmvc/resources/Spring-Dojo.js

Could some please point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: An update: i changed the urls for spring resources to <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring.js" />"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js" />"> </script>. This is still not working

Comment: Jack, they are under the app root.

Answer (score 0):

you have to play with the web.xml in this case.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch11s02.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have been using spring security, then you have to define the intercept url, like this:
`<security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" filters="none" />`